# Meta pixel server side google tag mamager failing

Tags: google-tag-manager

In my partner set up on my FB pixel , when I try to connect to my server side container it fails, it had connected the first time then I realized I have connected it by mistake, then I deleted everything from my tag manager and published the new version and I have tried to do the set up again but everytime fails at the last step.(Conversions API Tag)

Any one can help?

the message pops up:
Publishing Failed
We weren't able to publish the resources to your Google Tag Manager account. Please try again.

Blockquote

Answer (score 1):

The same error was sent to me. I went back to my GTM web container and FB had generated some tags for both the FB pixel and a GA4 config tag  . **I'd check your container to see if there are new tags. If not, I'd look into manually setting up Facebook tracking tags in GTM** (that's what FB tried to do for us anyway in that set-up form).

I guess FB just can't publish from that button sometimes? No idea why. There are other places to test your setup and a manual GTM publish isn't so bad I guess. Oh well. I really liked this video on FB tracking for SS: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JNResY4jJZA

Answer (score 0):

I have the solution

I did the same thing, partially setup Conversion API, then tried to redo it correctly the second time.

I was running into that error message.

What I had to do to make it work was deleted every single Tag, Trigger, and Variable that Facebook had published and then retry.